# Sharing *compilation* window with other compilation-like commands

Tags: window, compilation

Is it possible to make a few different commands share a window for their output? For example, let's say I do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile` and get a `*compilation*` buffer in bottom half of my frame. If I then do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ack` (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `grep`, etc.), I would like the results of these commands to be displayed in the same window which `*compilation*` occupies.

Some background: In reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725015/how-do-i-make-the-compilation-window-in-emacs-to-always-be-a-certain-size/9728357?noredirect=1#comment44981053_9728357) @Francesco provided a [nice snippet](https://gist.github.com/ffevotte/d7e69cf147c014381003) which displays the compilation window at the bottom of the current frame. This works nicely to manage `*compilation*`, but it would be even nicer if `compile`, `ack`, `ag`, `igrep` and a few similar commands shared this window.

(So what I am really looking for is how to extend Francesco's snippet to manage the output of multiple commands together.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should work (independently of the snippet you mention to always create compilation windows at the bottom of the current frame).

Whenever you try to display a compilation buffer (or any buffer in a derived mode), `display-buffer-reuse-compilation-window` will try to find another currently displayed compilation buffer, and reuse the window. If there is no compilation buffer currently displayed, the standard action will be taken.

```
(require 'dash)

(defun display-buffer-reuse-compilation-window (buffer param)
  (message "toto")
  (let ((candidate
         (-find (lambda (b)
                  (and
                   (get-buffer-window b)
                   (with-current-buffer b
                     (derived-mode-p 'compilation-mode))))
                (buffer-list))))
    (when candidate
      (with-selected-window (get-buffer-window candidate)
        (switch-to-buffer buffer)))))

(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             (cons 
              ;; Condition
              (lambda (buffer action)
                (with-current-buffer buffer
                  (derived-mode-p 'compilation-mode)))
              ;; Action
              (cons
               #'display-buffer-reuse-compilation-window
               nil)))
```

A bit of warning, though: I'm not sure my snippet complies with all `display-buffer` options regarding e.g. the possibility to reuse windows in other frames.

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try to merge this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309340/managing-emacs-man-buffer-location/28311686 (your code shows how to check whether two buffers are compatible, there there is more fine-tuned frame-related logic).